# AngularJS Scope inconsistency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, this is making me tear my hair out.  We're integrating with some ATSs, so I send out some queries, and on receiving responses I set some variables in the scope.  I set the variables inside of a $scope.$apply(), so they should update properly - and it seemed like they WERE, until recently.  After debugging for an hour or two, I created a line that expresses the weirdness of the problem.  Consider the following code:

```
<div ng-show="aR.g" ng-bind="aR.g ? 'g yes' : 'g no'"></div>
```

Note that if shown, the text should be "g yes", and if hidden, it should be "g no".  However, the element was hidden, and upon inspecting it, I found the following:

```
<div ng-show="aR.g" ng-bind="aR.g ? 'g yes' : 'g no'" class="ng-binding ng-hide">g yes</div>
```

This means that ng-show evaluated aR.g to false, yet ng-bind evaluated aR.g to true.  How is that even possible?  Surely that's a bug?

Comment: Can you please show some of the other code (for example, where are you calling `$scope.apply`? That's not even usually necessary in the typical "activator" pattern, unless you're using your data in an isolate scope.)

Comment: @JoshBeam Sorry, but I'm not sure I can put my company's code here, and it would take a long time to make a minimal still-erroneous example.  Plus, I've figured out a workaround, which I'll post in a minute, though it's kinda horrifying in its potential for paranoia.

Comment: @JoshBeam By the way, though, I was using $apply because I had to change variables in the $scope inside a window message handler, for messages passed from my chrome extension.  (`window.addEventListener("message", function(event){<code>})`)

Comment: @Erhannis, it works under normal circumstances (i.e. if I try to repro it with a simple `$scope.aR = {}` object), so you have something else going on. We could sit here and guess, or you could show some repro code

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug some where else, making this part of code to crush. I've created a [pen](http://codepen.io/alihaghighatkhah/pen/vEWrxW) for you.

controller:

```
$scope.aR = {
    g: true
  }
```

View:

```
div(ng-app="app")
  div(ng-controller="TestController")
    div(ng-if="aR.g" ng-bind="aR.g ? 'g yes' : 'g no'")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible ussually to do it without apply. It is also possible to use

`ng-if="normalReadableName"` without ternary operator.

At first look into console if there isn't any error.

If not, its hard to say without the code but I suppose you are facing problem when directive above creates scope. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Or You are reasigning whole object so watch reffers to the previous assigned. Similar problem described here : [Update bootstrap angularjs table with real time data on the fly using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887360/update-bootstrap-angularjs-table-with-real-time-data-on-the-fly-using-ng-repeat/31887829#31887829)

Syntax "controller as" mentioned there could help if it is one of these problems.

Comment: Hmm.  "Reassigning the whole object" may actually be the issue.  I'll have to look into it next week.  I'll let you know what I find.  Thanks!

Comment: You welcome. Look at the controller as so watch will check property of object not primitive type. And let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I still don't know WHY it's like this.  But if you replace `ng-if="aR.g"` with `ng-if="aR.g ? true : false"`, it works as it should.  This is horrifying in that I now have no idea what parts of my logic will work as they should - it's not strictly a matter of simplicity of the expression or anything, as the actual part that was failing was, like, Z in `ng-if="X && Y != 'blah' && Z"`.  For some reason `ng-if="X && Y != 'blah' && (Z ? true : false)"` worked as expected.

I may have fixed my problem, but I'd appreciate if anybody knows how this could have happened - I'm now super paranoid about the rest of my code.